# Emacs modes: highlighting uses of variable under point

Tags: emacs

In Python mode, if I put the point on the `x` argument in the below function definition

```
def f(x):
  #   ^------ point here
  print x
```

the use of `x` in the function body gets highlighted in yellow.

- How does that work?
- If I were to write my own Emacs mode, how can I add such highlighting for my language?

Comment: The built-in Python Mode doesn't do that, nor any other mode in Emacs.  Are you using some starter kit, or did you install a 3rd party mode such as highlight-symbols?

Comment: @lunaryorn Appolgies. I am using starter kit. I wasn't aware it affected python-mode.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, there are 3 highlight libraries mentioned below - highlight-symbol (15k), hi-lock (31k), and highlight (137k) - hi-lock is part of Emacs. More info at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightTemporarily

Answer (score 3):

I'd not implement such a feature in a major mode itself.  A generic minor mode that tries to support as many major modes as possible based on generic Emacs interfaces (e.g. syntax tables) is a better fit, and unsurprisingly, someone already wrote such a mode: [highlight-symbol](https://github.com/nschum/highlight-symbol.el).

With this package and the following code in your `init.el`, Emacs will highlight all occurrences of the symbol (e.g. variable, function, class) under point:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'highlight-symbol-mode)
```

This package also provides a bunch of other utilities to work with the symbol under point, such as `highlight-symbol-nav-mode`, which lets you jump to the next and previous occurrence of the symbol under point with `C-n` and `C-p` respectively.  Take a look at the source to see what it's capable of.

Comment: Also, for specific case @tibbe is asking people might rather be interested in [color identifiers mode](https://github.com/ankurdave/color-identifiers-mode/).

Comment: Please note that `highlight-symbol` is buggy and unmaintained *(it haven't seen updates since 2016)*; nowadays [you better off using symbol-overlay mode](https://github.com/nschum/highlight-symbol.el/pull/53), which is basically a better rewrite of highlight-symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Command `hlt-highlight-symbol` in library [`highlight.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/highlight.el)  does what you want.  (See also option `hlt-auto-faces-flag`.)  It does what library [`highlight-symbol`](http://nschum.de/src/emacs/highlight-symbol/) does (including navigation among occurrences), and more.  See [Highlight library](http://www.emacswiki.org/HighlightLibrary).

Also, Emacs 24.4 (i.e., current development snapshot), command `hi-lock-face-symbol-at-point` does what you want, I think (differently).

Answer (score 1):

```
(require 'hi-lock)


(defvar args-highlighted-p nil)
(defvar args-highlighted-regexp "\_<.+\_>")

(defun highlight-args ()
  "With cursor at function's argument, highlight args in body.

When already highlighted, un-highlight. "
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (if args-highlighted-p
    (progn
      (setq args-highlighted-p nil)
      (hi-lock-unface-buffer args-highlighted-regexp))
      (let ((erg (prin1-to-string (symbol-at-point)))
        (end (funcall end-of-defun-function)))
    (if
        erg
        (progn
          (setq args-highlighted-p t)
          (setq args-highlighted-regexp (concat "\\_<" erg "\\_>"))
          (hi-lock-face-symbol-at-point)
          (while
          (re-search-forward "\_<erg\_>" nil t end)
        (hi-lock-face-symbol-at-point))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how that mode specifically does it, but [here](https://github.com/Inaimathi/emacs-utils/blob/master/highlight-tags-mode.el)'s a `highlight-tags` minor mode I wrote as a thought exercise a while ago that does something similar for matching `sgml` tags.

It doesn't do a very good job of figuring out which tags to hit, but the relevant parts for you would be `highlight-tags-update`/`hide`/`show` anyhow. Keep in mind that since an `sgml` tag only has one matching tag, I got away with just having a global pair of overlays for a buffer. Your use case might have more highlights, so you'll need to keep a list of them instead.

The way that yours would work in the abstract is:

1. Take the output of `word-at-point`
2. Find all occurrences of word in the following block (probably using some combination of the `python-nav-*-block` commands and `search-forward`)
3. Collect the `start`/`end` of each match
4. Create a new `overlay` for each `start`/`end` pair with `make-overlay`, and return the list of these overlays.

You'd then want a function that took the output of the above and stored it somewhere so that you could later `(mapcar #'delete-overlay overlays)`.

Finally, you'd add a `hook` to `post-command-hook` that ran a function to remove the old overlays and generate new ones.